# Saving the checked list item continuously when after coming back to the activity and select

Tags: android, listview

Hi I am new to the android & doing some simple examples. Exactly, i'm using two activities & it contains a list view on both. In that first list view (Activity1) is empty, the second list view(Activity2) has some list item with a checkbox. Now getting the selected item from the 2nd activity & listed in the first activity. It's fine but exactly what i want is again click 'add' button from the 1st activity it launches the second activity then select some item & save. This newly selected item not adding to the existing list value used in 1st activity. Can anybody help me out.

SecondActivity.java

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkedContactList = adapter.getSelectedItemArrayList();
        }
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),MainActivity.class);

            returnIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("result", checkedContactList);
            startActivity(returnIntent);
        }
    });
```

In MainActivity.java

```
private ArrayList<SelectedListModel> selectedArrayList = new ArrayList<SelectedListModel>();
List<Map<String, String>> dataList;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
dataList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
selectedArrayList = data.getParcelableArrayList("result");
Iterator<ArrayList<SelectedListModel>> it = selectedArrayList.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){SelectedListModel selectedModel = (SelectedListModel)it.next();
SelectedListModel selectedModel = (SelectedListModel)it1.next();
            String name1 = selectedModel.getName();
                String number1 = selectedModel.getNumber();
                Map<String, String> dict = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
                dict.put("name", name1);
                dict.put("number", number1);
                dataList.add(dict);
                //listdata.add(dataList);

            } 
SimpleAdapter adpt = new SimpleAdapter(this, dataList, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, new String[] {"name", "number"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
    selectedList.setAdapter(adpt);
}
```

Comment: please post your code..

Comment: added my activity codes...

Answer (score 0):

You can use startActivityForResult()
[Api Document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Call in activity 1

```
startActivityForResult( Activity2, Activity2RequestCode)
```

In Activity 2

```
int result = "Some message here";
output.putExtra(name , result);
setResult(RESULT_OK, output);
finish();
```

In Activity 1 get return value

```
onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
if (requestCode == ActivityTwoRequestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null)
num1 = data.getIntExtra(Number1Code);
num2 = data.getIntExtra(Number2Code);
```